# why in release mode it's compile and in debug mode it's not (solution configurtion)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I don't understand why this source code in release mode it does compile,
and in debug mode it doesn't,
and it show me full of linking errors,
why it happens?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 50>oddArray{};

    size_t count = 1;
    for (size_t i{}; i < oddArray.size(); i++) {
        oddArray[i] = count + 2;
        count = oddArray[i];
    }
    for (int i{}; i < oddArray.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << oddArray[i] << " ";
        if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0) std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";

    for (int i{ oddArray.size() - 1 }; i >= 0; i--) {
        std::cout << oddArray[i] << " ";
        if (i  % 10 == 0) std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol **vcrt_LoadLibraryExW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE** * **cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPEAUHINSTANCE**@@XZ)  PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol **vcrt_GetModuleHandleW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE** * **cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPEAUHINSTANCE**@@XZ)    PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol **vcrt_GetModuleFileNameW referenced in function "struct HINSTANCE** * **cdecl GetPdbDll(void)" (?GetPdbDll@@YAPEAUHINSTANCE**@@XZ)  PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf_s referenced in function _vsprintf_s_l   PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj)    1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__invalid_parameter referenced in function "public: int & __cdecl std::array<int,50>::operator[](unsigned __int64)" (??A?$array@H$0DC@@std@@QEAAAEAH_K@Z)   PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\Main.obj  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__CrtDbgReport referenced in function "public: int & __cdecl std::array<int,50>::operator[](unsigned __int64)" (??A?$array@H$0DC@@std@@QEAAAEAH_K@Z)    PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\Main.obj  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__calloc_dbg referenced in function "char * __cdecl std::_Maklocstr(char const *,char *,struct _Cvtvec const &)" (??$_Maklocstr@D@std@@YAPEADPEBDPEADAEBU_Cvtvec@@@Z) PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\Main.obj  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp_wcslen referenced in function "wchar_t * __cdecl std::_Maklocwcs(wchar_t const *)" (?_Maklocwcs@std@@YAPEA_WPEB_W@Z)   PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\Main.obj  1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __C_specific_handler_noexcept    PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj)    1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4   PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(gshandlereh4.obj) 1
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __CxxFrameHandler4   PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\Main.obj  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _wsplitpath_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned __int64)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPEB_WPEA_W_K@Z) PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _wmakepath_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned __int64)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPEB_WPEA_W_K@Z)  PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW referenced in function _CRT_RTC_INITW PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(init.obj) 1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReport referenced in function _CRT_RTC_INIT   PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(init.obj) 1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol wcscpy_s referenced in function "int __cdecl GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath(wchar_t const *,wchar_t *,unsigned __int64)" (?GetPdbDllPathFromFilePath@@YAHPEB_WPEA_W_K@Z)  PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(pdblkup.obj)  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol strlen referenced in function "char * __cdecl std::_Maklocstr(char const *,char *,struct _Cvtvec const &)" (??$_Maklocstr@D@std@@YAPEADPEBDPEADAEBU_Cvtvec@@@Z)    PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\Main.obj  1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol strcpy_s referenced in function "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (?_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPEAXPEBD@Z)    PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj)    1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol strcat_s referenced in function "void __cdecl _RTC_StackFailure(void *,char const *)" (?_RTC_StackFailure@@YAXPEAXPEBD@Z)    PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib(error.obj)    1
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol memcpy referenced in function wmemcpy    PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\Main.obj  1
Error   LNK1120 19 unresolved externals PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\x64\Debug\PracticeMasm.exe 1
Warning C4267   'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data    PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\Main.cpp  20
Warning C4267   '=': conversion from 'size_t' to '_Ty', possible loss of data   PracticeMasm    C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\Main.cpp  10

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the exact message for (some of) the linking errors you're getting.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to link to some library in debug mode. Is this the actual code with the problem?

Comment: 1201ProgramAlarm, i add the errors. drescherjm, and yes this is the code

Comment: Why is it finding MSVCRTD.lib in a PracticeMasm directory?  Looks like your search path is messed up.

Comment: Mark Tolonen , how can i fix that?

Comment: Inspect your PATH environment variable, or remove msvcrtd.lib from that directory.  It is normally found in the visual studio library path anyway.

Comment: Delate this file: `C:\Users\zinma\source\repos\PracticeMasm\PracticeMasm\MSVCRTD.lib` and verify there are not other Microsoft libraries in this folder.